# Why is my mouse lagging so much it's impossible to use?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

I've a little logitech mouse, and suddenly, with no reasons, it started to lag heavily, and now it's impossibile to use. I've a MBP mid 2012 13'', and never had problems, but now it is unusable. The mouse is ok, i've tried it on another mac and it works fine. I've already tried to reset the controller, but nothing changed.

I really can't understand what could  be the problem? when i restart the mac it works fine for a while and then restart lagging.

Any ideas or similar experience?

Comment: I'm going to take a shot in the dark and guess you are using a Logitech V470. I have one too.. and it lags horribly. It is either a hardware issue or a driver issue but there is no fix for it either way. I ended up buying a Microsoft sculpt mouse to replace it and I have had no issues. What logitech mouse are you using exactly?

Comment: sorry, bad shot :D i've a M305, and for months it worked perfectly! ty for the try

Comment: Hmm interesting. Ok so it works fine on other Macs but not your own. I am going to guess it is either your Macs bluetooth or a software issue. Have you updated recently?

Comment: nope... no updates recently....

Comment: Well I'm sorry I wasn't much help. If I could make one suggestion I would try to install the Logitech software that they provide for OS X. You can find it here: http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/wireless-mouse-m305?section=downloads&bit=&osid=35

Comment: Have the same problem, but it only occurs when I have an external monitor plugged in. As soon as its unplugged the mouse starts working normally.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem with my 2011 17" MBP and Apple magic mouse.  Frustrated the hell out of me.  I turned off Handoff (Continuity) on my iOS devices and the problem has since disappeared.

Comment: Wow didn't expect this to help but it did!

Comment: I'm using a logitech trackball with wireless USB (not bluetooth).  It was lagging terribly.  I turned off "handoff" on my mac and that fixed it.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

It's radio interference and how OS X handles it and Logitech handle it.  since one of the tags by the OP is "bluetooth" I think it's safe to say that a Logitech BT mouse is in use here.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth):

> Bluetooth is a wireless technology standard for exchanging data over
>   short distances (using short-wavelength UHF radio waves in the ISM
>   band from 2.4 to 2.485 GHz[4])

You know what else uses 2.4Ghz spectrum of wireless?

WiFi and the  Logitech Unifying Receiver

I had a Logitech MX Master BT mouse that worked perfectly on Windows 10 on a Surface Pro 3.  On my iMac on the exact same desk, the mouse lagged.  All I did was switch from SP3 to iMac and the issues showed up.  I have the same problem with the unifying receiver as well, though not as bad.  It works perfectly on Win10, but lags on Mac.    It has been documented on [Logitech forums](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Keyboards-and-Keyboard-Mice/K750-Mac-MX-Master-and-terrible-lag/td-p/1382592).

When I was researching it, it came down to a driver and how either Apple or Logitech had to do something to fix the BT connectivity issue.  I didn't save the link, but when I get time, I will re-search again for it and post it here.  So basically, it's something the hardware manufacturer has to address.  There's nothing outside of getting a different BT mouse from a different manufacturer that will fix the problem.