# WiFi performance terrible when Bluetooth mouse connected on MacBook Pro (Sierra)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi, bluetooth

(Similar to [Why do my Macbook Pro's WiFi speeds drop significantly when paired with Bluetooth devices?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184788),  [MacBook Pro WiFi doesn't work when Bluetooth is on](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255804), and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8028129)

On my MacBook Pro running 10.12.6, whenever my Bluetooth Apple Magic Mouse is connected, the WiFi is practically useless. Speeds drop to less than 1 kbps, sometimes no connection at all.

I've searched and tried every solution I could find:

1. Removing the "Bluetooth PAN" network interface.
2. Using 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz WiFi networks.
3. Deleting config files from `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`
4. Resetting PRAM/NVRAM and SMC
5. Setting a new network location with custom MTU and DNS

Nothing fixed the issue. The instant I turn off Bluetooth, my WiFi is back to normal.

Apple suggested upgrading to 10.13 but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: Which MacBook Pro?  See this relevant post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119767/why-is-my-mouse-lagging-so-much-its-impossible-to-use/228186#228186  Also, is there a reason you don't want to implement the ***recommended*** fix?

Comment: It's a MacBookPro11,3. (I don't want to upgrade to 10.13 because I use Adobe Premiere heavily and there have been issues.) That post you mention; are you suggesting it's a hardware issue? Apple designed a Bluetooth mouse that would interfere with its own WiFi card? And why wasn't it an issue with 10.11?

Comment: No, in that post I state that it's a *driver* issue.  See the last paragraph.

Comment: Oh, I see ... and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You have two options:  1)  Get a wired USB mouse.  2) Update macOS.