# How to change bluetooth frequency for magic mouse 2

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, bluetooth, mouse, performance

1. Sometimes my Magic Mouse does not work when Wi-Fi is on!
   When I turn Wi-Fi off, I can move it again!
2. MacBook freezes frequently and it really drives me crazy! I guess it isrelated to the Wi-Fi, because when I turn Wi-Fi off, MacBook works better.

MacBook 2019 - Mojave 10.14.6

I read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119767/why-is-my-mouse-lagging-so-much-its-impossible-to-use) question about Logitech mouse.  But I use magic mouse 2, not other brands.

I read [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8639075?answerId=250182320022#250182320022) Apple Discussions article. My modem frequency is 2.4 GHz too. and unfortunately, it supports  only this frequency.

Can I change Bluetooth frequency from 2.4 GHz to something else?

Comment: The issue is the same as the other question they are both Bluetooth mice. (Although

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The 2.4 GHz frequency is what bluetooth uses so you would need to move to a place with less interference, turn off the conflicting devices to keep using [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.4_GHz_radio_use) reliably.

There are other frequencies mice, but Apple doesn’t make them. Look at Microsoft or Logitech if you don’t know where to start with mice that have a USB receiver and use other radio frequencies.

> Bluetooth devices intended for use in short-range personal area networks operate from 2.4 to 2.4835 GHz. To reduce interference with other protocols that use the 2.45 GHz band, the Bluetooth protocol divides the band into 80 channels (numbered from 0 to 79, each 1 MHz wide) and changes channels up to 1600 times per second

So, if you have interference bad enough that BlueTooth can’t accomodate or negotiate a channel, something is really wrong. I would focus on software updates, resetting devices, turning off WiFi for 30 minutes to be sure you really have an interference problem

Comment: thanks for your reply, changing the wifi band can reduce interference? I set it to the auto channel.

Comment: Yeah, no. See my edit @D.JCode

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing something similar, and it is actually the Apple Magic Mouse 2 that creates all the interferences with other Bluetooth devices.
I guess something got very wrong in my mouse. If it is on, no Bluetooth device works properly